# Bundle install fails as thrift installing is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

To resolve this I was trying command

```
gem install thrift -v 0.9.3 -- --with-cppflags=\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value\"
```

```
ruby '2.5.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
```

Error--

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-cppflags="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing thrift:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/ijain/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thrift-0.9.3.0/ext
/Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20211001-32631-1mcuep1.rb extconf.rb --with-cppflags\=\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE\=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value\"
/Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/shellwords.rb:84:in `block in shellsplit': Unmatched double quote: "\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0" (ArgumentError)
        from /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/shellwords.rb:82:in `scan'
        from /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/shellwords.rb:82:in `shellsplit'
        from /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1756:in `dir_config'
        from /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:2552:in `init_mkmf'
        from /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:2595:in `<module:MakeMakefile>'
        from /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from /Users/ijain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:23:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ijain/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thrift-0.9.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ijain/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.5.0/thrift-0.9.3.0/gem_make.out
```